# What is this called? And how to achieve it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, textbox, literals

I would like to make a WRITE A NEW POST page similar to ASP.NET

or

how to make a page similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Please note,

I do not want reference to already made controls like free rich text editor, etc.

I would like to do the required coding myself.

I would also like to know what is the name given to this kind of page? As I search Google for how to make a post and it comes up with GET and POST methods of HTML.

Initial attempt:-
on button click post back event within the update plane,

```
literal1.text = textbox1.text
```

assuming that user will provide formats like **bold**,
but the textbox is not taking any such input.

Comment: If I were you, I would try to learn first, and then this kind of questions will be automatically self-answered :)

Comment: Possibly related question [What is a good client side markdown editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357022/what-is-a-good-client-side-markdown-editor)

Comment: Do you even have to ask why this was downvoted? A good summary of the question would be `I want to learn a client side scripting language` (note that there isn't even a question in that summary, that's on purpose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If it's at all an option for you, I would suggest using ASP.NET MVC instead of WebForms.  Although there's a bit more of a learning curve it is a more appropriate abstraction for web development.*

Although most of what you are trying to do is fairly straight forward, you're right, regular TextBox controls will not take HTML input.  The [StackOverflow editor](http://github.com/derobins/wmd) is a custom built editor that uses [MarkDown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) syntax.  There's some interesting information on their implementation of the editor here (in no particular order):

- [Markdown, One Year Later](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/markdown-one-year-later/)
- [Three Markdown Gotchas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/three-markdown-gotcha/)
- [Reverse Engineering the WMD Editor](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/)